# Sync Google Chrome Bookmarks to different Google Accounts

Tags: google-chrome, sync, bookmarks

How can I sync the bookmarks from my google chrome to my other computers (who are signed in to Google Chrome with different Google accounts)

Comment: Hi, Kashif! Did you find a solution to your question? I am also interested in this

Comment: Nothing reliable.

Comment: What a pity....